# Unity script only working on one gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

This script in short changed the color of the gameobject it's attached to when the bullet goes through it.
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class targetHit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material oldMat;
    public Material newMat;
    Renderer rend;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "bullet")
        {
            hitTarget();
        }
    }

    void hitTarget()
    {
        rend.material = newMat;
        StartCoroutine("waitThreeSeconds");
    }

    IEnumerator waitThreeSeconds()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        rend.material = oldMat;
    }
}
```

`

However it only works on the game object highlighted in the image attached.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w2k2.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because rend = GetComponent(); called in Start, if image not attached to Gameobejct, rend will be null. So without image component attached to the GameObject, this script will not work.

Comment: Please elaborate, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you assigned the material files in the inspector, instead of assigning the "rend" variable on start, try instead assigning it the same way, for all GameObjects that use the script. Please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: I should re-word my question, it sometimes works on the other game objects although it's inconsistent. When I assign the renderer in the inspector, it is a little more consistent but still not working how I would like it to.

Edit: It also seems to work better the closer my player (with the gun attached) is to the target.

Comment: How does your bullet move? Does it move via Transform.Translate? Or Rigidbody.AddForce? If it’s Transform.Translate, then it is probably, in the occasion this script doesn’t work, translating directly to the other side, depending on the movement speed of the bullet.

Comment: I've changed it to Rigidbody.AddForce and it's working a lot better. It still sometimes doesnt work though. I'm not sure why but I'll keep testing.

Comment: Addition to my other comment. It seems to be something with the bullet speed. The faster it is, it doesnt detect the collision.

Comment: I believe, even using `Rigidbody.AddForce`, when the force being added is large enough, the applied translation (from the Rigidbody) will still cause it to translate directly to the other side. But at least it is working more often now. I personally have never dabbled with ray tracing, but it may be a viable option, instead of only detecting collisions, if you know how, try to ray trace and see if the players shoot direction should have hit. But that would probably also be difficult, so it is just a suggestion.